# Angular Material 16 issue with chipGrid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an issue with my angular material chip.
I am using angular 16 and material 16 as well.

This is all my dependencies:

```
"@angular/animations": "^16.0.4",
"@angular/cdk": "^16.0.4",
"@angular/common": "^16.0.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^16.0.4",
"@angular/core": "^16.0.4",
"@angular/forms": "^16.0.4",
"@angular/material": "^16.0.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.4",
"@angular/router": "^16.0.4",
"@ctrl/ngx-codemirror": "^7.0.0",
"@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker": "^16.0.1",
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.10.1",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
"@types/chrome": "^0.0.154",
"@types/node": "^20.3.0",
"@vimeo/player": "^2.15.0",
"byte-base64": "^1.1.0",
"chart.js": "^3.7.1",
"core-js": "^3.20.2",
"country-flags-dial-code": "^1.2.0",
"dexie": "^3.2.4",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"file-saver": "1.3.3",
"flag-icon-css": "^3.4.6",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"json2typescript": "^1.5.1",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"ng2-file-upload": "^3.0.0",
"ngx-cookie-service": "^16.0.0",
"ngx-device-detector": "^6.0.1",
"ngx-permissions": "^15.0.1",
"ngx-select-ex": "^8.0.1",
"ngx-sharebuttons": "^13.0.0",
"pace-progress": "1.0.2",
"papaparse": "^5.4.1",
"paper": "^0.12.15",
"perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
"pretty": "^2.0.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
"rxjs": "^7.5.2",
"simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
"tslib": "^2.3.1",
"typescript-ioc": "^3.2.2",
"typescript-map": "^0.0.7",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
"xp.css": "^0.2.3",
"zone.js": "~0.13.0"
```

This is my angular template code:

```
 <mat-chip-grid #chipGrid aria-label="Enter fruits">
      <mat-chip-row *ngFor="let lang of languages"
                    (removed)="remove(lang)"
                    [editable]="true"
                    (edited)="edit(lang, $event)"
                    [aria-description]="'press enter to edit ' + lang.name">
        {{lang.name}}
        <button matChipRemove [attr.aria-label]="'remove ' + lang.name">
          <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-chip-row>
      <input placeholder="New Lang..."
             [matChipInputFor]="chipGrid"
             [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
             [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
             (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"/>
    </mat-chip-grid>
```

In the chrome dev tool, I see this:

[image]

If I drill down , It gets me to the piece of code in my template.

[image]

We have a working example on StackBLitz:

https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fexample%2Fchips-form-control-example.ts

Imports in my typescript chip class

[image]

Below is the code is my code for Material Chip Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialChipsInputComponent } from './materialChipsInput.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MaterialModule} from '../../material.module';
import {MatChipsModule} from "@angular/material/chips";
import {MatIconModule} from "@angular/material/icon";
import {MatFormFieldModule} from "@angular/material/form-field";
import {MatLegacyChipsModule} from "@angular/material/legacy-chips";
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MaterialModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatLegacyChipsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule

    ],
  declarations: [
    MaterialChipsInputComponent

  ],
  exports:[MaterialChipsInputComponent]
})
export class MaterialChipsInputModule {

}
```

Comment: Show us the material module imports.

Comment: No. I mean where you import the chip module. Also, don't use images of code here for this, paste the code and set format accordingly, pls.

Comment: You are importing both the new chips module and the legacy one as well. I would suggest removing the legacy module import and work with the new module (and API) only.

Comment: @Pes thank you so much. The legacy module was causing the issue. I removed it and now everything is working beautifully

Comment: Glad I could help. I will post the comment as answer so that you can mark that as accepted answer and close as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing both the new chips module and the legacy one as well. I would suggest removing the legacy module import and work with the new module (and API) only.